# vb 9 net activate links on richtextbox

Tags: .net, richtextbox, hyperlink

I have a richboxtext, I have some text with links on it. How do active them? Now they are fount, cursor changes to hand, I can press them but nothing else happens. I would like when I click it opens in a browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected Sub Link_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.LinkClicked
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText)
    End Sub

Here we are me :))